# What's the best logic to return TRUE in VBA if month NAMES are 1 apart?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to return `True` for the following examples:

**Example 1**

```
Date 1: 7/31/14   
Date 2: 8/1/14
```

**Example 2**

```
Date 1: 12/31/07  
Date 2: 1/1/16      (notice one year is 2007)
```

and `False` for the following example:

**Example 3**

```
Date 1: 7/31/14
Date 2: 9/1/14
```

What is the smartest way to go about this? I know I can use the `Month()` function and test whether the months are either different by `1` or `11`, but that seams like a bad solution

Comment: Have you looked into the `DateDiff` [function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php)?

Comment: The last example would be false because it's 2 months apart (July and September)

Comment: Sorry, should've read the title once more.

Comment: I definitely misread the post, deleted my (incorrect) answer.  Apologies.

Comment: No worries.  I think Jeeped has a really clever solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple boolean logic and maths should suffice.

```
Sub dts()
    Dim Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date

    Date1 = DateSerial(2014, 7, 31)
    Date2 = DateSerial(2014, 8, 1)
    Debug.Print CBool(Abs((Month(Date1) - (Month(Date1) = 1) * 12) - (Month(Date2) - (Month(Date2) = 1) * 12)) = 1)

    Date1 = DateSerial(2007, 12, 31)
    Date2 = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)
    Debug.Print CBool(Abs((Month(Date1) - (Month(Date1) = 1) * 12) - (Month(Date2) - (Month(Date2) = 1) * 12)) = 1)

    Date1 = DateSerial(2014, 7, 31)
    Date2 = DateSerial(2014, 9, 1)
    Debug.Print CBool(Abs((Month(Date1) - (Month(Date1) = 1) * 12) - (Month(Date2) - (Month(Date2) = 1) * 12)) = 1)

End Sub
```

Results:

```
dts
True
True
False
```

You added both [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) and [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula) to your question. If used as a worksheet formula, remember that TRUE is 1, not -1 as in a VBA True.

Comment: This is a good solution, thanks.  Is the Cbool definitely necessary?  Isn't it already defaulting to a boolean type?  Should I add a CInt() for the other test if that's the case instead?

Comment: I use `CBool` more than I need to because I often rely on numbers to be considered True or False. CBool just helps me visually see that I am treating numbers as booleans and not as numbers. In reality, False is zero and anything that is not False is True.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the year, then it seem's perfectly legit (and even best) to use the build in `Month` function, like this:

```
Public Function AreMonthsOneApart(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Boolean

    Dim lMonthsApart As Long
    lMonthsApart = Abs(Month(date1) - Month(date2))
    AreMonthsOneApart = (lMonthsApart = 1 Or lMonthsApart = 11)

End Function
```

In fact, using anything besides the `Month` function is probably going to be more complex.

(Even @Jeeped's solution uses `Month` in his calculations. It's going to be very hard to get around--Use `Month`!)

Comment: You forgot to compensate for a December - January pair.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to combine `Abs()` with `Mod()` in the following formula:

```
Abs(Month(Date1) - Month(Date2)) Mod 10 = 1
```

For example:

```
Dim Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date

Date1 = DateSerial(2014, 7, 31)
Date2 = DateSerial(2014, 8, 1)
Debug.Print Abs(Month(Date1) - Month(Date2)) Mod 10 = 1

Date1 = DateSerial(2007, 12, 31)
Date2 = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)
Debug.Print Abs(Month(Date1) - Month(Date2)) Mod 10 = 1

Date1 = DateSerial(2014, 7, 31)
Date2 = DateSerial(2014, 9, 1)
Debug.Print Abs(Month(Date1) - Month(Date2)) Mod 10 = 1
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```